# Create Union type without hard-coding in Python3 typing

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, typing

In python3 typing, how can I create new type using `Union` without hard-coding?

My attempt was, let's say I want to creat `Union[int, float]`, as follows, which ends with `SyntaxError`:

```py
from typing import Union
types = [int, float]
T = Union[*types] # want to create T = Union[int, float]
```

Comment: Would this even be useful? This would certainly break any static analysis, which is one of the main benefits of type hinting. I don't think any linters would be smart enough to use hints like that. This also would make self-documentation less effective, which is the other major benefit.

Comment: FWIW, it doesn't error if you use a tuple instead of a list: `types = int, float; Union[types]`

Comment: Python's type annotations are designed to be a *static* type system (unlike the actual dynamic runtime type system). What you're looking for goes directly against static typing. Even if it runs without error at runtime, it'll break mypy analysis, annotation-based IDE help, and anything else that tries to perform static type analysis.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Ok, I understand. The point is non-hard-coding type creation before runtime. So some meta programming seems to be reasonable approach, though I'm not sure mypy can handle meta programming

Comment: @user2357112 there is always a space of very useful statically analyzable constructs between "needs to be computed at runtime" and "can be expressed with statically hard-coded literals and simple variable substitutions". Plenty of things out there that are constant by the time the static type analyzer runs but nicer to express with constructs like splat operators or loops or conditional branches. I don't know why Python type checking needs to relearn the lesson of how powerful and useful this can be, when other languages already have, but I'd like us to wrap up the learning process faster.

Comment: (For example, code compatible with old versions of Python might import a type on versions where it exists within a `try` or `if`, and then needs some way to include it in a union if it exists, but not include it in a union otherwise. Now that specific case might not warrant a splat, but I've way to express it would be to have an empty list before the conditional import, and append the imported type into that list if it's available, then splat the whole thing. This is still trivially and quickly statically analyzable, the analysis is just not implemented.)